# Find the pattern in these numbers

Tags: pattern, english

> 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 3

How did I get those numbers and how do I get more that fit the pattern?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the pattern comes from:

> the letter count of the names of the numbers 1 to 10

Because

> one has 3 letters, two has 3 letters, and so on.

Comment: And you always end up at FOUR https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csInNn6pfT4